# Is it possible to proxy a subset of the hosted repository with sonatype nexus?

Tags: maven, rsync, nexus, sonatype

In our organization we have one instance of nexus that acts as a central repository for maintaining builds. In the current setup when we try to deploy a build into production, the deployment entity queries the nexus instance to fetch the appropriate build. I am trying to rearchitect the nexus setup and create nexus instances local to every datacenter in order to facilitate the deployment entity to quickly fetch the artifact.

For deployment purpose i only need our "Releases" hosted repository. The repository contains more than 20 projects and the repository has grown more than 200G in size. I only need 10 latest builds from all the projects in the datacenters. I was wondering if there is a way to fetch (proxy) only n latest builds from the remote repository and not the entire repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the 'Evict Unused Proxied Items From Repository Caches' configuration option:
http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-managing-tasks.html

(Note that by default, your downstream proxy only fetches items when they're requested, so they won't be 200G to start with)

Comment: and you can use Smart Proxy with Nexus Professional to automatically populate the datacenter specific repositories as soon as a deployment on the main Nexus instance happens.